# Authorize.NET payment gateway is not working in development environment

Tags: java, ubuntu, authorize.net

I have integrated Authorize.net api in my application. it is working fine in my local environment(windows) also worked fine in Development environment(Ubuntu) upto last week. But suddenly it is not working in the development environment. The log says that it is unable to connect to autnorize api server. Can anybody help me on this. Below is the log message.

```
    2017-05-11 07:02:04 INFO  HttpClient:24 - Use Proxy: 'false'
2017-05-11 07:02:04 DEBUG BasicClientConnectionManager:158 - Get connection for route {s}->https://apitest.authorize.net
2017-05-11 07:02:05 DEBUG DefaultClientConnectionOperator:174 - Connecting to apitest.authorize.net:443
2017-05-11 07:02:05 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:176 - Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@136dcd8 closed
2017-05-11 07:02:05 INFO  DefaultHttpClient:623 - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Connection reset
2017-05-11 07:02:05 DEBUG DefaultHttpClient:627 - Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:533)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at net.authorize.util.HttpCallTask.call(HttpCallTask.java:72)
    at net.authorize.util.HttpCallTask.call(HttpCallTask.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-05-11 07:02:05 INFO  DefaultHttpClient:629 - Retrying connect
```

Comment: The URL is https://apitest.authorize.net.  Is it the correct production URL for the payment gateway?

Comment: Yes that is correct, We are still not in production mode. Still using this in sandbox mode.

Comment: The sandbox now requires a TLS 1.2 connection.

Comment: How to add TLS 1.2 @rhldr

Comment: You might try the solution from another developer at https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/GetAcceptPaymentPage-API-is-not-working-even-after-change-of-Jdk/m-p/58030#M32707